# delete empty row (space) in series python

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe, series, isnull

I have a series contains cleaned tweets
but i see some tweets becomes empty after cleaning

I'm trying to use isnull().sum() but result was 0

```
df['cleaned'].isnull().sum()
```

**I need to calculate how many this empty row(contains just space such this ' ') in series and delete it.**

**note: empty is ' '
not null**

Comment: Use `df = df[df['cleaned']!= '']`

Comment: not working !!!!